# Displaying several SSRS reports as labels on one "report"/page

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report

I have a SSRS (.rdl) report sitting on remote server (on the same intranet network) that displays data, based on one parameter, let's say "ProjectID".

In my MVC application I have an interface for choosing several ProjectIDs for preview and printing.
The report is shown to the user by simple line "**Return New RedirectResult(strURL)**" including the parameter "ProjectID" which shows the web page of SQL Reporting Services website with the report.

Questions:

- Is it possible to show 4-6 instances of this report on one page, as if it is a "list of labels"?
- How would I pass parameters if I want to show the number of reports with different ProjectID?

**The ultimate goal:** to let the user choose projects from the check box list and view/print reports, as the user got used to in ACCESS application.

If it is not possible, I would appreciate any other solutions to my issue.

Regards,
Eugene

P.S. I'm a vb.net guy, but with pretty dissent knowledge of c#.

Comment: From the SSRS side, there are various options, but as you already have a report that accepts a single ProjectID, I would use this existing report as a sub-report and then create a master report that accepts a list of ProjectIDs . Here's an answer to a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983953/create-multiple-tables-according-to-a-list-input-in-ssrs-reports/67984793#67984793

Comment: Thank you Alan. The problem is - list(array) of parameters is supposed to be sent from the application. Not to be displayed to the user on SSRS Services site. My problem is SENDING list of parameters to Master report.